# ¿Como pasar un diccionario a una matriz? algoritmo BFS

Tags: python, matrices

Estoy desarrollando el algoritmo BFS para hallar el camino más corto dentro de un grafo dirigido. El grafo lo estoy trabajando en una lista de adyacencia que después lo derivé a un diccionario. El algoritmo se ejecuta bien

> ```
> def BFS(graph, s): #graph es el diccionario con el grafo
>     depth = {s: 0}
>     frontier = [s]
>     while len(frontier):
>         current_node = frontier.pop(0)
>         for neighbor in graph[current_node]:
>             if neighbor not in depth:
>                 depth[neighbor] = depth[current_node] + 1
>                 frontier.append(neighbor)
>
>     return depth
> ```

Y se imprime bien, aunque no en bloque, toca hacerlo uno por uno. Para la impresión de 3 nodos, devuelve lo siguiente

> ```
> print(BFS(graph, 1))
> print(BFS(graph, 2))
> print(BFS(graph, 10))
> ```

```
{1: 0, 6: 1, 7: 2, 2: 3, 8: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6, 9: 7, 5: 8, 10: 9} #nodo 1
{2: 0, 8: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 9: 4, 5: 5, 10: 6} #nodo 2
{10: 0} #nodo 3
```

Como mi intención es hacer una matriz de distancia a partir del algoritmo, mi pregunta es ¿Cómo hago para que me muestre un valor, puede ser ficticio (como -1 o infinito) cuando los nodos no tienen conexión alguna entre ellos? todo con el fin de que cada diccionario tenga el mismo tamaño.

Edit:

Logré establecer el -1 cuando no había conexión con dos nodos distintos, de la siguiente manera

> ```
> for node in graph:
>         if node not in depth:
>             depth[node] = -1
>
>     return depth
> ```

```
{1: 0, 6: 1, 7: 2, 2: 3, 8: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6, 9: 7, 5: 8, 10: 9} #nodo 1
{3: 0, 4: 1, 9: 2, 5: 3, 10: 4, 1: -1, 2: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1} # nodo 2
{10: 0, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 5: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1, 9: -1} #nodo 3
```

sin embargo, cuando quiero imprimir todos los nodos dentro del diccionario de una sola vez mediante:

> ```
> for node in graph.keys():
>     print(BFS(graph, node))
> ```

Aparece en consola lo siguiente:
for node in graph.keys():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

e imprime solo la primera fila, es decir la del nodo 1.

¿Saben cómo resolver este problema? para después poder pasar todo el diccionario a una matriz nxn
Gracias

edit: Solución, tienen que crear un diccionario vacío, para que no les aparezca el error

> ```
> graph = defaultdict(dict)
> edges = set()
>
> for i, v in enumerate(adjacency_matrix, 1):
>     for j, u in enumerate(v, 1):
>         if u != 0 and frozenset([i, j]) not in edges:
>             edges.add(frozenset([i, j]))
>             graph[i].update({j: u})
>
> for i in range(1, len(adjacency_matrix)+1):
>     print("{}: {}".format(i, graph[i]))
> ```

Comment: No entiendo bien qué pretendes. ¿Podrías completar la pregunta con un ejemplo que incluya qué contiene la estructura de datos `graph` de tu ejemplo y cómo querrías que fuese el diccionario de salida de la función con esos -1 extra?

Comment: Si claro, ya lo logré pero ahora se me presentó otro problema. Ya completo la pregunta

Comment: Listo, ya edité la pregunta

Comment: Haz `nodes=graph.keys()` y  después `for node in nodes:` Eso evitará el problema de iterar por un diccionario que está siendo modificado dentro de las iteraciones. No obstante, debo reconocer que sigo sin entender bien qué se pretende y sospecho que si lo entendiera podría dar con una solución mejor. Quizás tu función no debería modificar el grafo que recibe como parámetro, sino retornar otro como resultado.

Comment: Sí, sé que no me estoy dando a entender muy bien jaja. Mi intención es obtener la matriz de distancia a partir de una matriz de adyacencia, como la matriz que pienso trabajar es muy grande 700 x 700 estoy haciendo esto como prueba. Pasar una matriz de adyacencia 10x10 a una lista de adyacencia (y a un diccionario) y aplicar el algoritmo BFS pero tengo problemas cuando me arroja el resultado. Por ejemplo, con tu respuesta me acaba de arrojar el mismo error.

Comment: Podría copiar todo el código que llevo por si quisieras revisar

Comment: pues casi mejor copias todo el código a ver si entiendo qué intentas hacer. De todas formas veo que has hecho otra pregunta sobre el mismo tema ¿eso hace obsoleta esta otra pregunta? En ese caso bórrala...

Comment: Sí, es que encontré que el error estaba en la lista de adyacencia. Ya la borro. Gracias

Comment: Si encontraste el error, en lugar de borrar la pregunta, también puedes poner tu solución como respuesta, si consideras que puede ser útil a otros con un problema similar. Incluso pasado un tiempo puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Comment: Listo, de hecho, fue la respuesta que me diste. ¿De casualidad abufalia, sabes cómo pasar esa lista de diccionarios a una matriz ordenada? He estado buscando y no hay nada preciso, me sale un arreglo escalonado

Comment: Cuando decía que incluyeras la respuesta, me refería a que lo hicieras como respuesta, no como edición de la pregunta. De ese modo también podrás "marcarla como aceptada". Aunque si en realidad se trata de la solución que yo di a tu otra pregunta, tal vez esta pregunta sobre por completo. Respecto a la consulta que me haces... casi mejor que creas una pregunta nueva en la que puedas explicar un poco mejor qué es lo que buscas, y qué es lo que has conseguido hasta ahora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución, tienen que crear un diccionario vacío, para que no les aparezca el error

> ```
> graph = defaultdict(dict)
> edges = set()
>
> for i, v in enumerate(adjacency_matrix, 1):
>     for j, u in enumerate(v, 1):
>         if u != 0 and frozenset([i, j]) not in edges:
>             edges.add(frozenset([i, j]))
>             graph[i].update({j: u})
>
> for i in range(1, len(adjacency_matrix)+1):
>     print("{}: {}".format(i, graph[i]))
> ```